# Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8_general_ci">
            <title> sistema de cadastro</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <nav> 
        <ul class="menu">
            <a href="index.php"<li>Cadastro</li></a>

            <a href="consultas.php" <li>Consultas</li></a>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        <section>
        <h1>Cadastro de Usuario</h1>
        <hr><br><br>
        <form method="post" action= "processa.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar" class="btn">
        <br><br>

        Nome <br>
        <input type="text" name= "nome" class= "campo" maxlength="40" required autofocus> <br>
        Email <br>
        <input type="email" name="Email" class="campo" maxlength="50" required><br>
        Profissao <br>
        <input type="text" name="Profissao" class="campo" maxlength="40" required><br>

        </form>


        </section>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

---

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "cadastro4";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database);
if (! $conexao){
echo "falha na conexao com o banco de dados";
```

---

```
<?php

include_once ("conexao.php");
$nome =$_POST ('$nome');
$email=$_POST ('Email');
$profissao=$_POST ('Profissao');

$sql = ("insert into usuarios3 (nome,email, profissao) values ('$nome', '$email', '$profissao')");

$salvar = mysqli_query ($conexao, $sql);


mysqli_close ($conexao);

?>
```

O erro que aparece:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\wamp\www\CADASTRO2\processa.php on line 4

Comment: Vejo alguns erros de sintaxe, mas por via das dúvidas: o `if` no arquivo `conexao.php` não possui a chave de fechamento mesmo?

Comment: Possui sim, é que na hora de selecionar tudo ficou de fora mas tem sim fechamento nele, estava fazendo vendo um tutorial no youtube segui tudo que ele fez só que no vídeo funcionou normal, já no meu apareceu esse erro de sintaxe

Comment: Pode adicionar à pergunta a mensagem completa do erro?

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\CADASTRO2\processa.php on line 4 ... está aparecendo essa mensagem de erro '

Comment: Variável `$_POST` índice `nome` não é com parêntese, nas colchete

Comment: No titulo da pergunta você está apresentando um erro, no corpo outro, e não explica nada sobre eles.

Comment: Eu estou usando notepad+++  para editar tudo, e nele quando eu coloco entre conchetes aparece mais erros                                                   (  ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: Nome in C:\wamp\www\CADASTRO2\processa.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.5960 133376 {main}( ) ..\processa.php:0  )

Comment: O @JeffersonQuesado Já disse onde está o erro. Se o comentário dele não te servir, por favor edite a pergunta colocando detalhes do seu código completo.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.!

Answer (score 2):

O erro em si ocorre na linha:

```
$nome = $_POST('$nome');
```

Ao utilizar parenteses, o PHP irá analisar `$_POST` como sendo uma função e tentara executar sua chamada passando um parâmetro do tipo *string*; porém, a variável superglobal `$_POST` é do tipo *array*, que não é chamável, gerando o erro que diz que o nome da função deve ser uma *string* (e não um *array*).

> Nesta linha, também, você utilizou `$nome` ao invés de apenas `nome` como definido no campo do formulário HTML.

No PHP, existem duas formas possíveis de se acessar uma posição de um *array*: utilizando colchetes, que é a forma tradicional, ou utilizando chaves.

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];  // colchetes
$nome = $_POST{"nome"};  // chaves
```

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php):

> Tanto colchetes quanto chaves podem ser utilizados intercambiávelmente para acessar elementos de um array (por exemplo, `$array[42]` e `$array{42}` irão fazer a mesma coisa que o exemplo anterior). *[sic]*

Assim, o correto seria:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$profissao = $_POST['Profissao'];
```

> **Nota**: seria interessante manter a constância no código. Ou define todos os nomes iniciando com letra minúscula ou com letra maiúscula. Misturar os dois, embora não tenha efeitos colaterais diretos, deixa o código mais confuso e menos legível.

Também, evite definir uma *string* entre parenteses sem necessidade, como fez em:

```
$sql = ("insert into usuarios3 ...");
```

Os parenteses externos são desnecessários e também deixam o código menos legível, pois espera-se que, em uma expressão, os parenteses sejam utilizados para controlar a ordem de execução de operadores dependendo de seu nível de precedência. Não é este o caso.

Aproveitando a resposta, a mensagem de erro sobre a conexão com o banco pode ser melhorada, pois, da forma atual, quando a conexão não for bem sucedida, a mensagem será exibida e o código continuará executando. Como o resto do código depende diretamente de uma conexão devidamente aberta, não faz sentido executá-lo quando ocorrer o erro, portanto, seria melhor se você matasse a execução ali, substituindo `echo` por `die`:

```
if (! $conexao){
    die("falha na conexao com o banco de dados");
}
```

Assim, quando a conexão não for estabelecida, a execução é encerrada.

Comment: Deu tudo certo com essa programação consegui cadastrar os dados no banco de dados. Obrigado ! ... Não querendo abusar da sua boa vontade mas queria pedir uma outra ajuda com outra programação, queria conectar um site de um trabalho da facul em php em um banco de dados ..

Comment: @GabrielLima isso seria assunto para outra pergunta, mas você já faz a conexão com um banco de dados com PHP nessa pergunta, então não entendo qual seria a dificuldade; o código é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

> Function **name must be** a string

"Traduzindo a função `name` deve ser uma string"

A variável `$_POST` é um array então como mencionado nos comentários, deve alterar os parênteses por colchetes, e referir os índices tal qual o `name` dos `inputs`:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email= $_POST['Email'];
$profissao= $_POST['Profissao'];
```

Outro detalhe, `include_once` dispensa os parâmetros nos argumentos, então:

```
include_once "conexao.php";
```

> Pelo fato do include ser um construtor especial da linguagem, parênteses não são necessários ao redor do argumento. Tome cuidado ao comparar valores de retorno.[¹](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)